# Rails simple_form nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms

I have 2 models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contact_people

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_people
end

class ContactPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I cand add a new `Client` or a new `ContactPerson` separately with no problem.

I want to create a form where I will be able to add them both with a nested form. What would be the recommended way to do this, create a new controller to do this and create new and create action for that, or use the `ClientsController` and create a new method there?

If a new controller is recommended, how can I access the params? Also, will validations will work here?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the `attributes` of your both models.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what exactly do you mean.

Comment: I mean your `column names` of your `clients` and `contact_people` tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the **`new`** and **`create`** methods of your **`ClientsController`** to do something like this

```
Class ClientsController < ApplicationController

   def new
      @client = Client.new
      @client.contact_people.build #this is very important
   end

   def create
     @client = Client.new(client_params)

     if @client.save
     redirect_to @client
     else
     render 'new'
     end
   end

   private

   def client_params
     params.require(:client).permit(:client_attr1, :client_attr2,.., contact_people_attributes: [:id, :contact_people_attr1,:contact_people_attr2,..])
   end
 end
```

And the view code would be something like this

```
<%= simple_form_for @client, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @client.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 #your client attributes code here

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :contact_people do |cp| %>
    #your contact_people attributes code here
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the validations you are talking about can be set normally in models.

Comment: Yes, but in this case I will not be able to use the create controller to create only the `Client` object ... right?

Comment: @HMihail Yes,you can't.But you said you want both.

Comment: I want to be able to create also single objects, like `Client` and `Contact Person`, but I also want to create some sort of wizard-style form where to create both together already linked. Sorry for not making it clearer.

Comment: @HMihail You didn't mentioned those in the question.For to create both `Client` and `ContactPerson`,this is the answer.